# Realm for React-native. reset database

Tags: react-native, realm

I'am new in realm with react-native.

I change schema often, but get migration error everytime I change.

How do I reset realm database when I change schema?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can just delete the app from the device or the simulator to reset the Realm.

Comment: If you want to wipe simulator clean, you may use "Simulator > Reset Content and Settings..."

Answer (score 2):

**Using Android Emulator Genymotion**

In your app

```js
const realm = await getRealm();
console.log(realm.path);
```

**copy** the result from console.log () which will be the path of your .realm file.

**In (Cmd or Terminal)**

```js
adb shell rm /data/data/com.example.package/files/default.realm
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends, if you are using Genymotion (for ANDROID simulation) you would use a different approach. Please note that for both approaches (XCODE & GENYMOTION) you will be reseting the `simulator` to factory settings...

Here are the steps I used to do this for Android :

1. Open **GenyMotion Manager**
2. Select the `Virtual Device` (e.g. ***Samung Galaxy S6***).
3. **If you are on OSX.** Press CMD + F (*reverts to factory setting*)
4. **If you are on WINDOWS.** Press CTRL + F (*reverts to factory setting*)
5. You can *also* do this by **RightClick** action on the item and selecting
   `(Reset this virtual device to factory state)` on your device.
6. Enjoy!

Comment: Unfortunately resetting virtual device is not available in free version of Genymotion.