# How to delete a table (class in schema) in the domain database is not reaction native?

Tags: react-native, realm-mobile-platform

Good afternoon, all right ?, 
I am new non-native to reactive and am having to use Database, non-native territory to reagent but wanted to know if it was deleted as table (Schema class already created).
Thank you very much in advance.

```
versions
"react": "16.8.6",
"react-native": "0.60.5",
"realm": "^3.2.0",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using Android Emulator Genymotion**

In your app

```js
const realm = await getRealm();
console.log(realm.path);
```

**copy** the result from console.log () which will be the path of your .realm file.

**In (Cmd or Terminal)**

```js
adb shell rm /data/data/com.example.package/files/default.realm
```

[Realm for React-native. reset database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35639286/realm-for-react-native-reset-database/58963138#58963138)